# Laravel: Get Request is not supported when uploading images in Trix Editor. although method is POST

Tags: php, laravel, post, get

I have a ridiculous problem. when I try to store a new product without uploading images in Trix Editor ( ***description field in the products table*** ), It's done and the product is stored successfully.
But when I upload image in the description I got the error and it is:
[image: Get method is not supported]
Although the method is still POST
[image]

I think the problem is trix editor make a sooo much long link for the uploaded image, like this:
[image: long link for the uploaded image]

I also checked the Host configuration and here it is:
[image: Host Configuration]

So, where is the problem?
Note: this error is not exist in localhost